# json decode returns empty string

Tags: php, curl, json

here is my origin code:

```
$returnArray=array(
    'loginUrl'=>$url."/?page_id=2732",
    'clientNumber'=>$clientNumber,
    'clientName'=>$_SESSION['userName']
);
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

and here is my receiving end code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$result = trim(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

And finally here is the `$result` var_dump

```
string(194) "
{"loginUrl":"http:\/\/www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.il\/chtsystem\/?page_id=2732","clientNumber":"11111","clientName":"\u05d0\u05d1\u05d9 \u05d4\u05de\u05d3\u05d1\u05d9\u05e8 - www.yyy-yyyyyyy.co.il"}"
```

`$result` comes out `null` from the decode, when printing json errors I can see `"JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX"` is on

what is wrong here?

Comment: You have a new line or a BOM character before output. check that.

Comment: @MihaiIorga does a leading newline trip `json_decode`? I don't think it should.

Comment: @JanDvorak i was to lazy to correct myself, I wanted to say that there is a new line that is generated by an UTF8 BOM character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in having a leading new line in your JSON string. But you probably have a UTF-8 BOM and `json_decode()` can't cope with that.

The most likely source for the BOM is your IDE or text editor. Verify its settings and make sure that UTF-8 files are saved without BOM. Such BOM is not mandatory and it normally just creates problems like this one.

**Update:**

You can replace this:

```
var_dump($result);
```

... with this:

```
var_dump(bin2hex($result));
```

... to obtain a more accurate view of your JSON string contents. A [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) would reveal itself as:

```
efbbbf...
```

Comment: well i have saved both ends using UTF-8 no BOM and still it comes out NULL

Comment: Use [bin2hex()](http://es1.php.net/bin2hex) to determine the exact character before the actual JSON output.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how to use ?

Comment: @liorr - Alright, I see I'm not being clear. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks , this is the result
string(120) "efbbbf0a3c64697620636c6173733d27657272273ed79ed7a1d7a4d7a820d794d79ed7a9d7aad79ed7a920d7a9d792d795d799203c2f6469763e2d31"

Comment: @liorr - Would you like me to determine whether your string begins with "efbbbf"?

Comment: oh sorry :-) didn't notice your last line , ill check it again